# Remove all numbers before the period in a Double with NumberFormatter not working - Swift

Tags: swift, numberformatter

I'm trying to remove all digits before the `.` period in a `Double` using `NumberFormatter` but for some reason, it only removes it if the digits are zeros.

Is it normal that when stating `formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 0` it doesn't remove all digits before the `.` unless they're zeros?

```
func formatDoubleAsStringFraction(number: Double)->String{
    var formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2 // two digits after the decimal point
    formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 0 // this will remove digits before Idecimal point
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    let formatedNumber = formatter.string(for: number)
    
    return formatedNumber!
}


formatDoubleAsStringFraction(number: 0.99) // outputs: .99
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(number: 000.99) // outputs: .99

formatDoubleAsStringFraction(number: 1.99) // outputs: 1.99 - why it doesn't remove the 1?
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(number: 123.99) // outputs: 123.99 - why it doesn't remove the 123?
```

Comment: `minimumIntegerDigits = 0` means zero or more digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `maximumIntegerDigits = 0`

That should force your output to have no integer digits. It worked in a quick test I did.

### Edit:

This code:

```
func formatDoubleAsStringFraction(number: Double)->String{
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2 // at least 2 digits after the decimal point
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2 // no more than two digits after the decimal point
    formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 0 // this will remove digits before the decimal point
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    let formatedNumber = formatter.string(for: number)

    return formatedNumber!
}

for _ in 1...10 {
    let value = Double.random(in: -100...100)
    print("formatDoubleAsStringFraction(\(value)) = \(formatDoubleAsStringFraction(number:value))")
}
```

Yields test output like this:

```
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(4.157493934834335) = .16
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(-87.6652867247289) = -.67
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(-23.442326432705002) = -.44
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(-49.424727272130696) = -.42
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(44.03922384656289) = .04
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(46.795543920754454) = .80
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(42.842058609346736) = .84
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(-44.274898907193275) = -.27
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(93.86270874357706) = .86
formatDoubleAsStringFraction(16.953208660898483) = .95
```

Which seems to match your desired output.

(Note that if you want exactly 2 fractional decimal digits, you probably want to set both `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits`.)

Comment: It did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Apple is pretty deliberate (and generally pretty good) with naming the properties of it's classes. Think about the name as an English phrase. If you want to limit the **maximum** number of integer digits, look for a property that mentions maximum digits.

Comment: By the way, if you're using this in production code, and using it to parse large volumes of values, it's better to create your number formatter once and save it in an instance variable. Apple has said in the past that creating a number formatter is somewhat expensive.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice and the great examples. In production, I have the `NumberFormatter()` as an instance property.  Thanks.